# MS SQL, Subqueries and EXISTS ERROR

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, exists

I have a MS SQL 2012 database the table has 6 columns

```
ID
JobDate DATETIME
DriverID INT
JobNUmber NVARCHAR(20)
JobStart TIME
JobEnd TIME
```

I am trying to generate a query that will give me a single row for each day for each driver that has the day, the count of JobNumbers, earliest JobStart and latest JobEnd (this part was easy) and then the total hours and total minutes and a total of minutes. The second part I can only get to work if I do each specific day and driver separately. (eek!)

I am getting the error where "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Here is what I am trying to make work.

```
DECLARE @mnth NVARCHAR(20) = 'Jan-16'
DECLARE @FROM NVARCHAR(20) = '2015-12-28'
DECLARE @TO NVARCHAR(20) = '2016-01-31'

SELECT @mnth AS 'Month',
x.DriverID As 'Driver',
DAY(x.JobDate) AS 'Day' ,
COUNT(x.JobNumber) AS 'Stops',
MIN(x.JobStart) AS 'Start',
MAX(x.JobEnd) AS 'End',
(SELECT
    SUM(hrs) AS 'Hours', SUM(mins) AS 'Minutes', SUM(ABS(hrs * 60) + (ABS(mins))) AS 'Total Minutes'
    FROM
    ( SELECT
        ABS(SUM(E_hrs - S_hrs)) AS hrs,
        ABS(SUM(E_mins - S_mins)) AS mins
        FROM
            (SELECT
                DATEPART(HOUR,MIN(j.JobEnd)) AS E_hrs,
                DATEPART(HOUR,MAX(j.JobStart)) AS S_hrs,
                DATEPART(MINUTE,MAX(j.JobEnd)) AS E_mins,
                DATEPART(MINUTE,MIN(j.JobStart)) AS S_mins
                FROM Xora_Job_Time j
                WHERE j.JobDate = x.JobDate
                AND j.DriverID = x.DriverID
            ) a
        ) b
) c
FROM Xora_Job_Time x
WHERE x.JobDate >= @FROM
AND x.JobDate <= @TO
GROUP BY DriverID, DAY(JobDate), JobDate
ORDER BY DriverID, DAY(JobDate)
```

This part works great!

```
DECLARE @mnth NVARCHAR(20) = 'Jan-16'
DECLARE @FROM NVARCHAR(20) = '2015-12-28'
DECLARE @TO NVARCHAR(20) = '2016-01-31'

SELECT @mnth AS 'Month',
x.DriverID As 'Driver',
DAY(x.JobDate) AS 'Day' ,
COUNT(x.JobNumber) AS 'Stops',
MIN(x.JobStart) AS 'Start',
MAX(x.JobEnd) AS 'End'
FROM Xora_Job_Time x
WHERE x.JobDate >= @FROM
AND x.JobDate <= @TO
GROUP BY DriverID, DAY(JobDate)
ORDER BY DriverID, DAY(JobDate)
```

And gives me the information I am looking for but trying to add the time counts is causing this to fail with the EXISTS error.

This works but I'd need to do each day and driver by itself....

```
SELECT SUM(hrs)AS 'Hours', SUM(mins) AS 'Minutes', SUM(ABS(hrs * 60) + (ABS(mins))) AS 'Total Minutes'
FROM
( SELECT
    ABS(SUM(E_hrs - S_hrs)) AS hrs,
    ABS(SUM(E_mins - S_mins)) AS mins
    FROM
        (SELECT
            DATEPART(HOUR,MIN(JobEnd)) AS E_hrs,
            DATEPART(HOUR,MAX(JobStart)) AS S_hrs,
            DATEPART(MINUTE,MAX(JobEnd)) AS E_mins,
            DATEPART(MINUTE,MIN(JobStart)) AS S_mins
            FROM Xora_Job_Time
            WHERE JobDate = '2016-01-06'
            AND DriverID = '3') a
    ) b
```

The error I am getting is the subquery with EXIST and I don't see where I want an EXIST clause much less where it will help.

Nonetheless Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple records in a sub-select from the `SELECT` list like that.  I think what you're looking for is a [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
Declare @Mnth NVarchar(20) = 'Jan-16';
Declare @From NVarchar(20) = '2015-12-28';
Declare @To NVarchar(20) = '2016-01-31';

Select  @Mnth As 'Month'
      , x.DriverID As 'Driver'
      , Day(x.JobDate) As 'Day'
      , Count(x.JobNumber) As 'Stops'
      , Min(x.JobStart) As 'Start'
      , Max(x.JobEnd) As 'End'
      , c.Hours
      , c.Minutes
      , c.[Total Minutes]
From    Xora_Job_Time x
Cross Apply (Select Sum(b.hrs) As 'Hours'
                  , Sum(b.mins) As 'Minutes'
                  , Sum(Abs(b.hrs * 60) + (Abs(b.mins))) As 'Total Minutes'
             From   (Select Abs(Sum(a.E_hrs - a.S_hrs)) As hrs
                          , Abs(Sum(a.E_mins - a.S_mins)) As mins
                     From   (Select DatePart(Hour, Min(j.JobEnd)) As E_hrs
                                  , DatePart(Hour, Max(j.JobStart)) As S_hrs
                                  , DatePart(Minute, Max(j.JobEnd)) As E_mins
                                  , DatePart(Minute, Min(j.JobStart)) As S_mins
                             From   Xora_Job_Time j
                             Where  j.JobDate = x.JobDate
                                    And j.DriverID = x.DriverID
                            ) a
                    ) b
            ) c
Where   x.JobDate >= @From
        And x.JobDate <= @To
Group By DriverID
      , Day(JobDate)
      , JobDate
Order By DriverID
      , Day(JobDate);
```

A `CROSS APPLY` will execute the inner sub-query for each record, whose results can then be referenced by the `SELECT`.